# watsapp sharing in Angular 7 web Application

Tags: javascript, angular, whatsapp

I am working on an Angular Web Application,

Where I am trying to share my content on **web.watsapp.com**  https://web.whatsapp.com/ ,

I have tried it in two ways But it is not working

**here is my code**

**1st Attempt ->**

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Proof%20That%20European%20Festival%20Fashion%20Is%20Better%20Than%20American%20Fashion%0A%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buzzfeed.com%2Fazafar%2Fproof-that-european-festival-fashion-is-better-than-american%3Fbfwa">Share2</a>
```

**2nd Attempt ->**

```
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" data-href="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share1</a>
```

Comment: try to add this `action` to your 1st attempt `action="share/whatsapp/share"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to use whatsapp web then you can use this code

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share1</a>
```

if its for mobile whatsapp

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=www.google.com" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s" style="display:none">Share1</a>
```